I have some doubts about how to prove recurrence of a one-dimensional Brownian motion.
Specifically, the Theorem in question comes from Durrett's book (Probability: Theory and Examples). The theorem states the following:
Let $B_t$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion and let A= $ \bigcap_{n\geq 0}\{B_t = 0$ for some $ t \geq n\}$. Then $P_x(A) = 1$ for all x.
I am trying to prove the theorem but for an arbitrary constant c instead of 0.
I tried to prove it by using sets of the form {$B_n$ > c infinitely often } and {$B_n$ < c infinitely often} and use a theorem stating that if a set D is in the tail-sigma field, then $P_x(D)$ is either zero or one for all starting point x. I used the fact that both {$B_n$ > c infinitely often } and {$B_n$ < c infinitely often} have probability one, and their intersection is included in the set A defined above.
More specifically, let $B= \cap_{n\geq 0}( \{B_k > c$ for some $k\geq n$} $\cap$ $\{B_k < c$ for some $k\geq n \}) $= $\{B_n > c$ i.o.} $\cap$ {$B_n < c$ i.o.}, continuity of Brownian paths ensures that $B \subset A$. Moreover, using the Theorem mentioned above, the sets $\{B_n > c$ i.o.} and {$B_n < c$ i.o.} have probability zero or one for all starting point x, since they belong to the tail-sigma field.
Now, if we define $B_t^* = (B_t - B_0)$, the translation invariance property and the Brownian scaling relation give
$P_x(B_n> c $ i.o.$) = P_x((B_n - B_0) > c-B_0 $ i.o.$) = P_0(B_n^* > c-B_0 $ i.o.$) \geq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_0(B_n^* > c-B_0)$
$= \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_0(\sqrt{n}B_1^* > c-B_0) = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} P_0(B_1^*> (c-B_0)\sqrt{n}^{-1}) = \dfrac{1}{2} > 0$.
Meaning that $P_x(B_n > c$ i.o.) = 1 for all x. Similarly, $P_x(B_n < c$ i.o.) = 1 for all x. So set B is the intersection of two sets with probability one, which implies that it also has probability one. The inclusion $B\subset A$ concludes the proof.
I want to thank anyone who takes the time to answer my question.

Welcome to math.stackexchange. To improve your post (and avoid down votes and close votes), here are some suggestions. First, use mathjax for the math formulas. Also, read our guidelines for formatting and writing your post, where you'll find this: Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title.

Law of Iterated Logarithm for BM and continuity of paths give this immediately.

@LeeMosher, thank you for the advice, I used Mathjax as you advised me to and made it so that it is not necessary to use the link and removed it. I will make sure to keep this in mind in the future. Thanks again

@geetha290krm, thank you for your comment, but I do not think I am allowed to use this result as it is presented later in the book I am working with, and it is a result outside of the scope I am supposed to work with.

If using standard tools is outside your scope, then you should explain carefully what is allowed.

I apologize, I should have been clearer. I can only use the translation invariance property, scaling relation, and the theorem mentioned. I know multiple results could imply this result immediately, but I am not supposed to use them. My question is more about wether what I did for the proof makes sense rather than finding other ways to prove it. Thank you again for the advice
